# Matching conditions for perfect conductors in electro*dynamics*

Tags: electromagnetism, scattering, conductors, boundary-conditions

I've been working through the problems on Wald's [*Advanced Classical Electromagnetism*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism) and recently I dealt with the scattering of a plane, circularly polarized wave off of a perfectly conducting ball (Chap. 7, Prob. 9). For reference, the problem reads

> Obtain the exact solution for the scattering of a circularly polarized plane wave of frequency $\omega$ off of a perfectly conducting ball of radius $R$. [Hint: Follow the same strategy as outlined in the text for the case of a dielectric ball. Start with the expansion of a plane wave corresponding to Eq. (7.59)—consider only the case $m=+1$—and take the scattered wave to have the form of Eq. (7.60). Then apply the perfect conductor boundary condition $\mathbf{E}_{\parallel} = \mathbf{0}$ at $r=R$.]

For reference, Eqs. (7.59) and (7.60) read
$$(\mathbf{\hat{x}} \pm i \mathbf{\hat{y}})e^{ikz} = \sum_{l=1}^{+\infty} i^{l-1} \sqrt{\frac{4\pi (2l +1)}{l(l+1)}} \left[j_l(kr) \mathbf{r} \times \nabla Y_{l,\pm1} \pm \frac{1}{k}\nabla\times\left(j_l(kr) \mathbf{r} \times \nabla Y_{l,\pm1}\right)\right] \tag{7.59}$$
and
$$\mathbf{A}_{\text{scat}} = e^{-i\omega t}\sum_{l,m} \left[a_{lm} h_l^{(1)}(kr) \mathbf{r} \times \nabla Y_{lm} + b_{lm}\nabla\times\left(h_l^{(1)}(kr) \mathbf{r} \times \nabla Y_{lm}\right)\right] \tag{7.60}.$$
They simply correspond to the expansion in vector spherical harmonics of a plane wave and of a general solution for $r > R$. All of this is written in the Lorenz gauge with scalar potential $\phi = 0$.

I know how to solve the problem for $r > R$, which is what I think the exercise was going for. One just has to follow Wald's hint and match solutions at the surface $r=R$. However, I'm curious about the solution for $r < R$. More specifically, I'm not sure whether, given the information in the problem, one can determine the fields inside the sphere. My reasons are:

1. I know that if the sphere was a superconductor, the magnetic field inside it would vanish. I don't believe the outer solution would be modified by this (since it is completely determined by just imposing $\mathbf{E}_{\parallel} = \mathbf{0}$ at the surface), but I'm not fully sure whether "a perfect conductor" is enough information to conclude the magnetic field vanishes. Hence, I'm not sure whether "both fields vanish inside the material" is an appropriate matching condition for the problem and I tend to think that it isn't.
2. To find the inner solution, my usual approach would be to write the most general inner solution (which, according to Wald's text, is Eq. (7.60) with the Hankel functions swapped by Bessel functions of the first kind) and then impose that $\mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}$, $\mathbf{H}_{\parallel}$, and $\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ are continuous at the surface. However, I am not sure how to even compute $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ quantities for a perfect conductor, since I don't know what are its permittivity and permeability. Hence, I can't see how the usual matching conditions used for, e.g., dielectrics could be applied in here.

Hence, on the one hand, I'm not sure whether one needs more information to determine the inner solutions. On the other hand, "the ball is a perfect conductor" sounds to me like a phrase that should completely characterize the material.

In short, I think my question can be phrased in summarized, and general, form as

**Question:** Are there well-defined matching conditions for a perfect conductor in electro*dynamics* or does one need more information about the material in order to write them down? If there are such conditions, what are they?

To be clear, I do not expect nor want someone to actually carry the entire calculation or anything of the sort. I'm only interested in the conceptual aspect of how to deal with the matching conditions for conductors when fields depend on time and magnetic fields are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the definition of a "perfect conductor"<sup>1</sup> to be a medium in which $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) = 0$, then the magnetic field in a perfect conductor must be constant in time:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} = - \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0.
$$

This would then imply that the only possible interior solution is time-independent: $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathbf{B}_0(\mathbf{r})$.  In other words, there are no fields in the interior oscillating at frequency $\omega$, which is usually what we define as the "response" of an object to an incoming wave.  So in that sense, we can take $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t) = 0$ in the interior.

The sphere can, of course, have *static* fields inside (perhaps the conductor has a non-zero permanent magnetization?), but that would just mean that the full solution would be a superposition of two solutions:

- a solution where we have an incoming wave of frequency $\omega$ (and zero interior fields), plus
- a solution with a static, non-zero $\mathbf{B}$ inside the sphere and no time-dependence.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the definition given in Zangwill and in Griffiths, and I assume that Wald takes the same position.  Knowing Wald, I would also assume that this is carefully defined elsewhere in the text.

Comment: That makes sense. It is similar to how the complete solution can change depending on whether the net charge in the conductor vanishes or not. As for the footnote, Wald does define it in the same way elsewhere: *A* conductor *is a material with charges that are free to move within the material in such a way to make $\mathbf{E} = - \nabla \phi = 0$* (and adds a footnote mentioning that in Electrodynamics fields can penetrate materials of finite conductivity).